# Mysql read the "just-now" updated value

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I have searched and found something related to isolation level and "prevent dirty read". What I understood from my search was that I needed to isolate transaction level with READ COMMITED option (I am not sure about that though, still mysql begginner). What I want, however, is to make sure that when I get the information with SELECT it is, for sure, the updated information (the information could have been updated just instants ago and I would get the old info if I don't do anything about it...).

I think I understood the theory but I can't say the same about practice. 
My old query was like this (js):

```
var query = "SELECT name FROM user_info WHERE id = "+user_id+"";
// doesn't solve my problem...
```

How can I perform what I want? Something like this?

```
var query = "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITED SELECT name FROM user_info WHERE id = "+user_id+"";
```

Thank you.

EDIT: (this might help explaining...)
The client is able to perform certain actions and I want to forbide clients from doing those multiple actions too fast. When a client action is sent to the server I check in db if the player is able to do the action or not. If the action is done I update the db so the player cannot act until some time has passed. If the player clicks too fast he sends multiple calls to the server and before the action state is updated in db the if conditional that checks in the db if the player can act returns true (he can do it) and it shouldn't. The info doesn't get updated fast enough.

Comment: If this was sql server, you would set the isolation level to read uncommitted.  I'm not sure if MySQL supports that.  Besides, under what circumstances would it actually matter?  Select queries are always based on what the data was when the query was run.  The person's name could be changed 1 second later, and you would still end up with the old value.

Comment: @DanBracuk I updated the question. It might be easier to understand I what I require. Probably there is even a better solution...